# Знак препинания после перечисления

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания ставится перед "что" в предложении "Кольца, браслеты, серьги, ожерелья что только не украшают бриллианты"?

Answer (score 2):

***Кольца, браслеты, серьги, ожерелья** — что только не украшают (чем?) бриллиантами?*

Тире ставится после однородного ряда перед обобщающим словом "что".

Именительный падеж существительного ***бриллианты*** нужно заменить творительным, иначе смысл сообщения неясен (что и чем украшают).